# How to deploy previous commit?

Tags: git

Suposse my git log has 3 commits:

```
c3
c2
c1
```

After deploying `c3`, I realize something has gone wrong in production.

How do I deploy `c2` without touching or removing `c3`?

In my first attempt, I did `git checkout c2`, but then `c3` was gone.

**Note:** I don't use `git push`.

Comment: what do you mean with "deploy"?

Comment: yeah how are you "deploying" ?

Comment: I use this tool: https://github.com/LeanMeanFightingMachine/dploy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were well on your way. Use:

```
git checkout c2
```

You are now in detached HEAD state. Your commit c3 is not gone; you can switch back to it later: see below.

Now deploy again to your production server:

```
dploy ...
```

now if you want to continue your work where you left off:

```
git checkout c3
```

**more details**

when you do `git checkout c2`; you move your `HEAD` to the commit c2. If you run `git log` now; you will only see log message up to c2 (so not c3). If you want to continue working again ; you can move back to the tip of your branch using:

```
git checkout <your-branch-name>
```

Comment: Ok! Can you tell me please why when I do `git checkout c2` then `c3` disappears from `git log`? Now with your answer I know I can return to `c3`, but how do I find the hash for `c3` if it is invisible in `git log`?

Comment: add added this to my answer. probably `git checkout master` will do

Comment: `git checkout master` is a sweet tip, thank you sir!

Comment: You can also use `git log -all` to see commit even after `HEAD`. A very nice alias to use when you want an overview of the state of your branches / HEAD / stash is `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --all --decorate=full`